# Paypal single payout: How do i know when user accepts payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have a codeigniter website integrated with paypal. I have a user table in my database which keeps track of their funding. User can withdraw that money at any time and I am trying to send them money via paypal single payout rest api call. Is there any way I can get notified when user accepts it so that I can decrement their funding in my User Table?

Right now i am using this api from paypal and i am using synchronous call https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-single-payout/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using IPN, it's possible to set the recipient's address and the notification_url dynamically For more detail [check here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

So using this method it's possible for a payment to 'User ABC' to be made at your site, and for the payment to be sent to 'User ABC', and for the IPN notification from Paypal to post to a listener script at a URL at your site.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i am looking for. But when i do payout recipient type EMAIL, is that an echeck transaction type in ipn?